# Changing error display format in Rails ActionView Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to modify the default behaviour of showing errors before the form to show them next to the fields instead.

I'm using this to achieve that:

```
  ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance| 
      if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
        %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
         #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</span>) 
      else %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
       #{instance.error_message}</span>)
      end
   end
```

However, for some  reason, the result html is coded with entities, so it doesn't get displayed:

```
<div class="group">
    <label class="label" for="user_city">City and Postcode</label>
    <input class="text_field" id="user_city" name="user[city]" size="30" type="text" value="94-050 Łódź" />
    <span class="description">np. 00-000 Łódź</span>

  </div>
  <div class="group">
    &lt;label class=&quot;label&quot; for=&quot;user_street&quot;&gt;Address&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;validation-error&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;
         translation missing: pl, activerecord, errors, models, user, attributes, street, blank&lt;/span&gt;

    &lt;input class=&quot;text_field&quot; id=&quot;user_street&quot; name=&quot;user[street]&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; value=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;validation-error&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;
         translation missing: pl, activerecord, errors, models, user, attributes, street, blank&lt;/span&gt;

    <span class="description"> &nbsp;</span>
  </div>
```

How can I avoid the result being html_entitied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your string is not safe. You need call html_safe after the string generate

```
  ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance| 
      if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
        %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
         #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</span>).html_safe 
      else %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
       #{instance.error_message}</span>).html_safe
      end
   end
```